# How to remove tcpdump first and last lines?

Tags: linux, text-processing, tcpdump

I'm coding a script based on tcpdump, but I want to get rid of the first lines that indicates the verbose parameters and the last lines with the number of captured packets:

[image]

I just need the output packets, thanks

Comment: Please do not post textual data as image; it makes the text hard to search for, is problematical for the blind, etc.

Comment: @thrig In general, I agree with your comment. But here there is a rare case, where posting this as text would not have been better. The text here in the example data image is irrelevant, will thus never be used as input data for a function/script/invocation. But the arrows on the picture are an easy means to designate the lines he'd like removed. That said, I think the picture here is pretty much superfluous. The textual description would just need to be slightly better worded to entirely replace the picture.

Answer (score 2):

`tcpdump` stats and header lines are on `stderr`. So I recommend redirecting `stderr`  to `/dev/null`:

```
tcpdump 2>/dev/null
```